# How can I speed up my loop calling a command line tool in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, command-line

I have an ASP.NET page that gets a list of game server ip addresses (quickly) and loops through them running a command line tool against them to get special game server information.  I have to use the command line tool because I don't know how it works to get the information from the machines and I don't want to reinvent the wheel.  The looping is the slow part (surprise surprise).  Each command line tool run takes up to a second so with approximately 60 ip addresses polled on average, the page load can take from 30-60 seconds to render the results I need.

My obvious thought was "multithread that thing!"  Well, I tried that w/ thread pools but ended up with a hanging website if more than one person accessed the page at a time. This was only using 4-5 calls at a time up to the 60 making it a 10 sec load time.  So not only did it hang with multiple users, it was still too slow.  I'd be happy if I could get it to under 3 seconds.

I should mention this page is in a shared hosting environment.  I had a great solution before outside of the shared hosting environment but I had to cut costs and I'm trying to make it work w/ shared now.

Is there any hope?

Comment: You should be able to parellize, unless you are running into some kind of limitation of the tool or the OS. What does the tool do exactly ?

Comment: what is the tool ? and what are the special server informations that you can not find from asp.net ?

Comment: The tool gets specific game information from running games.  It is not something .NET can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't really be polling these servers "on demand." It would be better to use ASP.NET to show the list of server information, and some other process - like a windows service, or scheduled task - to poll the servers every couple of minutes to generate that list. To summarize: The service would create an XML file (for example) and ASP.NET would display it to users. This way, the amount of users viewing the page does not affect the amount of times you try to poll the servers.

**Update**:

You need to ensure the process that pings servers is a singleton. Specifically, a singleton is a class in which only a single instance can exist. In more general terms for your case, you need to set a global flag that says "i'm currently pinging servers" and another global datetime value to says "the last time i pinged the servers was at hh:mm:ss" - you could use the Application dictionary to store the boolean flag and the datetime. Each time someone loads your page, check the flag to see if it's already pinging the servers. If it is, don't do it. If the flag says ok, then check the current time against the last time you did it. If it's less than 5 minutes, don't do it. All of this should be done in a background thread. This thread should update an xml file in App_Data. All requests to your pages should render this data immediately. A page request should never block. If the file is not there on the first call, then return "ping in progress, try again in 5 minutes." Follow?

Read about the ASP.NET Application state dictionary here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms178594.aspx

Comment: Yes, I agree, however as mentioned in the post, I am trying to get this working in a shared hosting environment.  This environment will not allow custom scheduled .exe's to run.  I had it working well with a Windows service to DB before but had to cut costs and move to shared hosting.  In the mean time, I'm caching data so there are actually very few queries on the servers.

Comment: I posted on SO because I am holding out hope there are some other budget-friendly options I have not considered to solve this.  One idea I was thinking was to have my future home file server query a web service to make the 30 second call often to cache the data but I currently do not have that built yet.

Comment: You could still emulate a service-based approach by ensuring the process to ping the servers is a singleton.

Comment: I am not following.  Can you kindly explain further?

Comment: If my requirement is that people see the most up to date information with at most 30 seconds old info, I'm guessing this singleton approach will not work?  

1. 1st person visits, kicks off pinging, show friendly msg
2. 2nd person visits 10 min later, sees cached info to XML from first visit (very old - most likely not right) but kicks off pinging

Right?

Comment: ok, then use the first web request to start up a background thread which loops, sleeps and generates the file continually. Use the application scope dictionary to hold a flag which says the thread is running to prevent other requests from kicking off a background thread.

Comment: Wow, I've never heard of that before in IIS environment!  Do we think this is a good solution?  Before I jump right in, I want to make sure this approach will not be a bad user experience.  I'm liking it because it should afford a fast load time for everyone but the first user.  I'm wondering if IIS recycles mid ping, what might break?  I suppose it's as easy as not updating the XML file till the end so users will always see a full file.  Are there any issues firing up a looping background thread in ASP.NET?  I've never done that so not quite sure where to start. Thanks for all your help, x0n.

Comment: FYI, I found an article that speaks to x0n's suggestion. I am feeling more confident about giving this a shot. Although the approach is not recommended, it just might work for my budget non-enterprise needs. http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: @rutt Ah, I hadn't seen that article from Phil. No better man to back me up than a former PM on the asp.net team ;) I didn't know about that hostingenvironment.registerobject stuff. Nifty! Although I suspect you might not have full trust in your scenario. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Low tech solution might be to call a bat file that makes each of the exe calls, instead of the exe repeatedly from asp.net. Saves the repeated shells to the OS overhead

Each call to the exe can pipe the results to a text file, which can then be read back all at once, once control returns to the asp.net app from the bat.

If the list of ip's change, then the the asp.net application could create the bat file before running it.

Comment: Interesting outside of the box thinking.  However, I don't get how this speeds up the user experience for the user?  So it calls the bat but wouldn't the initial load take the 30-60 seconds to query them all?  I suppose after that it would be cached, but I'd want the data to be updated fairly often anyway.  I guess without a scheduled task as I had before in my own VPS, this is not a viable option?

Comment: Not really certain, but easy to test; just build the bat file manually and run it. Wasn't sure if your delay was caused by the repeated executions of the external program, which *might* run somewhat faster in the way I suggested; can't say I completely understand your scenario, but usually I like to rule out the easy to implement solution first.